# When I use bitbake to compile, an error occurs

Tags: bitbake

When I use bitbake to compile a java program, it prompts that the signature failed.
“jarsigner:unable to sign jar:java.net.ConnectException:Network is unreachable(connect failed)
unable to sign the jar files”,

However, when I manually compile the compilation script generated by bitbake, the compilation is successful.like this “./run.do_compile.3675”,this confuses me.

Answer (score 0):

It's just because bitbake restricts network access. If you need to access the network, please set the flag.you can set "do_compile[network] = "1" in your bb file,so that you can access the network.
https://git.openembedded.org/bitbake/commit/?id=0746b6a2a32fec4c18bf1a52b1454ca4c04bf543